# Elegant way to "construct" kind-of enum values in go

Tags: go, constructor, constants

I'm quite new to Go and would like to improve my code. I have a representation for access levels in Go like this:

```
type AccessLevelValue int

const (
    GuestPermissions     AccessLevelValue = 10
    ReporterPermissions  AccessLevelValue = 20
    DeveloperPermissions AccessLevelValue = 30
    MasterPermissions    AccessLevelValue = 40
    OwnerPermission      AccessLevelValue = 50
)
```

What I want is a "constructor" for `AccessLevelValue` to which I can pass a numeric value from `{10,20,30,40,50}` and that returns me the according `AccessLevelValue`. This is my current implementation, but it seems not so nice to me:

```
func int2AccessLevel(accessLevel int) *AccessLevelValue {
    if accessLevel == 10 { return AccessLevel(GuestPermissions)}
    if accessLevel == 20 { return AccessLevel(ReporterPermissions)}
    if accessLevel == 30 { return AccessLevel(DeveloperPermissions)}
    if accessLevel == 40 { return AccessLevel(MasterPermissions)}
    if accessLevel == 50 { return AccessLevel(OwnerPermission)}
    return nil
}

func AccessLevel(v AccessLevelValue) *AccessLevelValue {
    p := new(AccessLevelValue)
    *p = v
    return p
}
```

Is there any cleaner implementation that doesn't need the `if` statements and returns the same result?

Answer (score 2):

Note that unlike C enums, your `const` declarations define *some* values of `AccessLevelValue`, but in Go they are not considered to exhaustively define *all* valid values of `AccessLevelValue`.

Also, the values are integer constants - why are you passing around pointers to them?

You might consider a `switch` statement:

```
function int2AccessLevel(level_int int) *AccessLevel {
    switch level_int {
    case 10: return GuestPermissions;
    case 20: return ReportedPermissions;
    // ...
    default: panic("Unrecognized value for AccessLevel");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the hints - the `switch case` is definitely an improvement. I need to pass pointers though, due to an external library and its interfaces...

Answer (score 1):

As Austin Hastings [mentioned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/181270/80949), all `int` can be cast to `AccessLevelValue`.

What I would recommend you is to create a `IsValid` method on this type to check if the value is valid.

You may adapt the behavior of `int2AccessLevel` not to panic (return nil / return a pointer and `ok` boolean / return a pointer and an error...)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type AccessLevelValue int

const (
    GuestPermissions     AccessLevelValue = 10
    ReporterPermissions  AccessLevelValue = 20
    DeveloperPermissions AccessLevelValue = 30
    MasterPermissions    AccessLevelValue = 40
    OwnerPermission      AccessLevelValue = 50
)

func (a AccessLevelValue) IsValid() bool {
    switch a {
    case GuestPermissions:
    case ReporterPermissions:
    case DeveloperPermissions:
    case MasterPermissions:
    case OwnerPermission:
    default:
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func int2AccessLevel(level int) *AccessLevelValue {
    av := AccessLevelValue(level)
    if !av.IsValid() {
        panic("Provided level is not valid")
    }
    return &av
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(int2AccessLevel(10))
    fmt.Println(int2AccessLevel(15)) // will panic
}
```